# matplotlib - How to create a bar graph with list of strings and list of int

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a bar graph using a list of strings and list of ints. However, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects.
```

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

languages = ['Javascript', 'C++', 'Python']
users = [1220, 2334, 3232]

plt.bar(languages, users)

plt.show()
```

Comment: sample data works fine on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Bar takes two arguments. plt.bar(xrange,heights). Rather than inputting scalars as the x value, you should input [0,1,2] then assign the xticks to be the languages.

```
xvalues = np.arange(0,3,1) 
plt.bar(xvalues, users) 
plt.xticks(xvalues,languages) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know why my original code works fine on some systems while it shows an error on others?

Comment: Not sure, it works fine the original way on my system as well. What version of python/matplotlib are you using?